# Typescript Class with strict subset of properties from another class

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance

I'm trying to declare a class that has a subset of the properties from another class.  I see the Pick utility to help declare a type.  But if I have a class like this:

```js
export class A {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}
```

and I want to declare a class like

```js
export class B {
    b: string;
}
```

I'm not sure how to limit the properties that can live on B only to properties that appear on A.  I don't want to allow properties except for a subset of the properties on Class A.  Class B is meant to be an instance type behind a search form.

I've tried using

```js
type B = Pick<A, 'b'>
```

This works as expected, but I'd like a class of this type.

If I have class B `extend` this type, I can still add more properties outside of what is declared in A, so this isn't what I'm after.

Anyone know how to have this in Typescript or another, better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the base class `A` to a constructor that only returns an object with some of the fields. But be aware, this is a purely type system solution, if the properties are assigned in `A` they will still be present on the instance:

```
export class A {
    a: string = "";
    b: string = "";
    c: string = "";
}

// Just create type and the constructor without creating a new class
type B = Pick<A, 'b'>
const B: new () => B = A
let a: B = new B();

// Create a new class, but cast A to a constructor with just some properties.
class C extends (A as new () => Pick<A, 'b'>) { }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=50&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4EE4G8BQcRcKAXHGjFAJYB2A5nALxwBErA3IcQEbmU0GzNp25EE-KnUYt2XAL758MAJ5hgcAELCACtQQBrADxYANHADkPCwD58CCLUpbytYAHc4ACgCUzG1rCWPhIwPBkgSxunpq+XPaoGHAAwnCgMMC0ACaYXjjocNHefkwBeoYm5la2frhw8kA)

Comment: This isn't quite the direction I went, but it definitely helped and answered the question.  Thank you!

Comment: @JakeSmith would be awesome to have an example of the direction you took in case it helps the rest 

Comment: I'm struggling to find what area of code I was trying this on.  Obviously, I obfuscated the actual code that led me to ask the question, and chose class names like `A` and `B` and now I can't find what this was in reference to.  I apologize!  It does look like I might have stuck with `Pick` though and just dealt with what it didn't give me.